# Would A Ground Connection Be Considerd An Open Path?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits

Circuits that have ground paths to say physical earth (e.g. a rod driven into the earth ), would such a path technically be considered open as opposed to closed?

Comment: The path itself is a short-circuit (assuming it was made from a good conductor). But I am not really sure if that's what you were referring to.

Comment: You need to provide more context for your question: Are you asking about why there is a ground/earth connection for an electrical service connection at a home or business, or are you asking about the ground connection of an outlet or one a power supply (as opposed to a + or - connection)?

Answer (score 3):

A circuit is closed only if current can flow. This means that there must a continuous connection from the voltage source through the load and back.

If one point of your circuit is connected to ground, the circuit will only be closed if another part of the circuit or the source is also connected to ground. If there is only one connection to ground, then the circuit is open; no current can flow around the circuit.

Of course, it is possible to have a closed circuit that is simply connected to ground at one point. This is done with home power installations, for safety, as it prevents the circuit to float above ground potential, which could cause electric shocks. In that case, the circuit including ground will only be closed when another point of the circuit is also connected to ground. When that is done, current can flow from the circuit to ground and back to the circuit.

Comment: But is not the path from ground to the voltage source of a home technically a open path, unless there is some return path to source that I am not aware about?

Comment: Yes, the ground connection in your home is an open circuit - until something goes wrong and you touch a live wire.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, usually we refer to open circuit as a circuit where no current can flow, like a if a piece of wire was removed, so it is instead a short circuit, because current can flow freely to te ground.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is neither.  The ground connection established at the electrical service entrance for a home or business is simply a zero voltage reference. In most single phase services, there are "hot" wires which have a sinusoidal voltage signal, usually two out of phase. In the USA, they will be 60 Hz in frequency and ~170 V in amplitude giving an RMS voltage of 120 each. There is a third wire which is called the neutral which is a voltage reference connected to the power station, through the set of transformers installed along the way.

At the service entrance (basically, the meter base/main breaker box), the neutral is bonded to a thick wire attached to a copper rod driven into the ground. This is done to provide a **stable voltage reference** for the dwelling that matches the electrical company's reference. The neutral is directly connected to the ground at the main breaker.

From the breaker box, individual circuits will either have a single hot (120V RMS), neutral, and ground wire, with the hot and the neutral running through the breaker, and the ground wire connected directly to the ground rod. For "220" or "240" circuits, there are two out-of-phase hot wires connected to a double breaker, usually with no neutral, but with a ground wire.

The purpose of the ground wire running with the individual circuits is strictly for safety purposes to provide an uninterrupted path to the earth. The neutral on the 120 circuits is to provide the reference. The 2nd hot on the 220 circuits is to provide a different reference.  If a 220 device needs a neutral as well as the 2 hot wires, it is because the device actually needs to know where the "real" zero is, i.e., the negative voltage swing is important, or there is some safety circuit which requires the neutral.